# Run multiple windows Sap With Vba

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I open 6 SAP windows via VBA code. I put all the parameters, but I can not get them to run at the same time. VBA expects to complete a window to run next. Can someone help me?

Sample Code:

```
Set aw = session.ActiveWindow()
    aw.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "Transaction"
    aw.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    aw.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press

'Here he expects SAP to generate the report, but I'd like it to go to the next window and execute.

Set aw2 = session.ActiveWindow()
    aw2.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "Transaction"
    aw2.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
aw2.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press
```

Comment: To my understanding Visual Basic runs single threaded so it will step through line by line. It will wait until the current line is executed, before running the next line. There are some exceptions to this in SAP GUI Scripting and other References you may include, but it is a reasonable assumption to make to begin with.

I do agree though, it would be nice to run a series of transactions that will take a while to come back and do other things in the mean time.